# R foreach thread number limitations

Tags: sql, r, database, foreach, dbi

I need to perfoform some simple queries to a remote database through RStudio, result of each is a df which contains way more less than 500 rows. Ideaof my code is simular to the one below:

```
con <- /connection/    
date <- c("'2020-01-01'", "'2020-02-02'", "'2020-03-02'")
SQL1 <- "SELECT * FROM dbo.new WHERE ReportDate="
SQL2 <- "OR ReportDate="
res_list <- list()

res_list <- foreach(i = 1:(length(date)-1))%dopar%{
  result<-dbGetQuery(con, paste(SQL1, date[i], SQL2, date[i+1]))
```

In fact, I need to do like 60-70 queries like that and execution of every query can take from 5 minutes to 5 hours.

So, here is my question: how much queries will be executed at the same time?

Is this number limited by number of cores in processor (if so, are there any ways to change it without changing a processor), or executuion of every query from 1 to length(date) will start at the same time?

Comment: When the loop reaches `length(date)`, `date[i+1]` is undefined. Try `foreach(i = 1:(length(date) - 1))` instead. As for the question,  yes, you are limited by number of cores in processor. See `parallel::detectCores()`.

Comment: ok, so, can I change this limitation and will it be effecient?

Comment: You could also try [promises](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/overview.html).